# C++: Initialization of pointer to pointer to int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Here is the sample code that I ran on Visual Studio 2010:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int **p(NULL);
}
```

I get this error: `error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'`

But if I change `int **p(NULL);` to `int **p = NULL;` the above code compiles fine.

Checked this on GCC(Version:4.4.2) and both work fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: probably, you compiler doesn't support.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the compiler. Interesting! Note that `int*p(0);` works, whereas `int**p(0);` doesn't.

Comment: Note that if you define `typedef int* PINT;` and then write `PINT* p(NULL);` it also works fine. `int** p(NULL);` should definitely work as well. The fact that it doesn't is interesting.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/41946/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VC++ compiler seems confused about initializations of pointer to pointer ...

This works for example

```
int (**p)(NULL);
```

These don't

```
int *i;
int **p(&i);
int **o(NULL);
```

This works though

```
int (**p)(&i);
typedef int* intp;
intp *o(NULL);
```

etc... the pattern is initialization fails whenever two ** are present! I'd guess a bug! Someone from MSVC team might be able to confirm

Answer (score 0):

That is either a bug in the compiler itself, or possibly you've done something and asked something else.

MSVC10 support few features from C++11, such as the following:

```
int **p1 = nullptr;
int **p2{}; //initialized to nullptr!
```

You can try any of these. Both are fine.

Comment: That's totally different.. Focus on the question buddy.. :)

Comment: @Nawaz: I have not asked anything else other than what I have done :)

Comment: @omggs: in that case, it is **most definitely a bug** in the compiler. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, defect with Visual studio,  It works if i use c++ to compile @ http://codepad.org/ and run the following code

```
int main() 
{     
    int **p(NULL); 
    return 0;
}
```

Same works using g++ compiler as well.

Answer (score -6):

You get a syntax error: apparently NULL is not defined. You should include cstdlib.